# Bower: Warning: EPERM. Grunt cannot complete operation

Tags: javascript, macos, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, bower

i have downloaded IE8 win XP virtual machine for Mac OS X following instructions from here: http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/

I also downloaded AngularJS repository from GitHub (https://github.com/angular/angular.js)
but when i run "grunt test" it fails on:

Warning: EPERM, rename 'C:\Documents and Settings\IEUser\Application Data\bower\cache\packages\b49378d5565266ad51701fa65c017d3e_wildcard' Use --force to continue.

and the last entry in command line before this error is "bower: extract closure-compiler".

How can i get bower to work?

PS. I have tried everything from here https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/798 but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling Bower 1.2.8 and installing 1.2.5 instead fixed the issue. It must have been os-specific because 1.2.8 works fine on my Mac OSX Maverics.

Answer (score 2):

Updating to bower to 1.3.1 and doing a `bower cache clean` also fixes this bug:

```
npm uninstall -g bower
npm install -g bower
bower cache clean
```